# Linux file inaccessible and has "?" permission

Tags: linux, permissions, files

I have a file that has some strange permissions on it:

```
[root@host var]# ls -la                                                                           
total 248                                                                                           
drwxr-xr-x  32 root     root      4096 Nov 24 07:59 .                                               
drwxr-xr-x  27 root     root      4096 Nov 23 20:13 ..                                              
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root      4096 Jun 17  2008 account                                         
drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root      4096 Jun 17  2008 antiword                                        
drwxr-xr-x   2 pcap     pcap      4096 Jun 17  2008 arpwatch                                        
?---------   ? ?        ?            ?            ? backup                                          
drwxr-xr-x  10 root     root      4096 Jun 17  2008 cache                                           
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root      4096 Nov 18 20:37 cpq                                             
drwxr-xr-x   5 netdump  netdump   4096 Jun 17  2008 crash                                           
drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root      4096 Jun 17  2008 db
```

The file in question is "backup". I have tried searching for some information on what could be causing this but unfortunately finding it hard to find relevant information. Running any commands against this file results in "Permission denied"

Anyone come across a file like this before? Any commands I could run to remove it or restore it?

Cheers,

Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe also this folder contains a mounted filesystem which suddenly became inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen silly things like this when there's filesystem corruption.  A fsck should sort that out in fairly short order.

Comment: Thanks for the above, will have to organise a time to unmount /var and get back to you but it does seem like fsck will fix. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

above all I would suspect filesystem damage and do a fsck of the filesystem (in case of /var it first needs reboot into rescue mode).

If that won't help, please write what filesystem it is (as seen from mount command).